# It seems not possible to include in my project, a path to a folder, that has been imported as a linked resource in my project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have in my workspace two folders:

1. *foo*
2. *bar*

After opening my project *foo* in Eclipse, I navigated to the src folder (or inc folder - it makes no difference) in my project and then from the **file** menu, I selected **import** and then **Existing Filesystem** and then gave the path to *bar*, and selected the option to **Create links in workspace**.

(This would, in that dialogue, automatically check the two sub-options: "Create virtual folders" and "Create link locations relative to" PROJECT_LOC/WORKSPACE_LOC/etc. Maybe this is a moot point.)

Now, of course, I need to include the headers from the linked resource *bar* into my project *foo* somehow.

So, I click the **properties** of my project. And under **C/C++ General**, in the **Paths and Symbols**  tab, I add the path (as a workspace path) to the linked resource *bar* under **included directories**.

I tried both "/bar" (which is where *bar* is actually present in the workspace),

OR,

"/${ProjName}/src/bar" (which is where *bar* is added to the project as a linked resource),

and in both cases, the header files from the linked resource cannot be found.

BUT, if I instead, in this project properties window, included an absolute path to the linked resource *bar*, e.g. */opt/workspace/bar*, then the header files can be found.

This seems like a bug in eclipse, as linked below. I couldn't find if there were any fixes ever implemented for this issue.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=72940
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122945

Comment: The bugs referred to are Java Development Tools bugs, and in this case don't quite correspond, but they are talking about the same issues. This issue affects C devs more often, so it is fixed in CDT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is *how* the linked folders are being represented in your project (virtual vs. non-virtual) and how the `-I` argument is being resolved.

The Import filesystem wizard does a very different thing when choosing *Create virtual folders* or not.

### *Create virtual folders* checked.

In this case all the intermediary folders are virtual, i.e. they don't correspond to the folders on the file system. You can see this in a few places:

1. The icon overlay is a blank square:

[image]

2. Adding a file to that directory on the file system will not make the file appear in the IDE. This is because the individual files are linked, not their containing folders.
3. You can see this in the project properties like this:

[image]

**Effect** These folders are virtual, they don't correspond to anything actually on disk, so there is no equivalent at build time to pass to GCC, so they are omitted.

### *Create virtual folders* unchecked.

In this case the link is to just the root element. You can see this in a few place:

1. The icon overlay is a shortcut type arrow:

[image]

2. Adding a file to that directory on the file system will make the file appear in the IDE.
3. You can see this in the project properties like this:

[image]

**Effect** These folders are linked, so they correspond to something on disk, therefore at build time they are passed through.

### Final Complication

The last complication is that `"/${ProjName}/src/bar/inc"` is not the correct way to refer to the path. You are constructing arguments for GCC here, so you have to resolve to from the workspace representation of the location to the location on disk. Therefore, surround the whole thing with the `workspace_loc` variable `"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/src/bar/inc}"`

```
"/${ProjName}/src/bar" -> /foo/src/bar/inc
"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/src/bar/inc}" -> /tmp/so/git/bar/inc
```

### Full Example on GitHub

I have added a full example on [github](https://github.com/jonahkichwacoders/stackoverflow-42816181/) and I left the generated Makefiles checked in for your reference. My git root was `/tmp/so/git` when looking at the Makefiles.

Comment: Jesus ! Jonah! I want to accept your answer, based on just how much effort you put into it!

But I am lying in my bed right now. So, I can only test it tomorrow at work.

Comment: I want to add, one thing, though. As far as I remember, I could NOT uncheck "create virtual folders", but I will confirm that tomorrow morning.

Comment: As far as unchecking "create virtual folders", there are conditions you can't uncheck it (although I didn't know that until you asked). I would recommend for creating the linked resources that you. I think it happens when you don't select *everything* to import. You may find it easier to create a new linked folder and avoid the import wizard for this case. When creating new folder (or file) expand "Advanced>>", choose  *Link to alternative...* and then use the Variables button so you don't hard code paths on your machine, but make them relative to something else (e.g. PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC)

Comment: OK. That seems to have done the trick. It wasthe "create virtual folders" that was the problem.

I added the linked resource in a different way. Instead of "importing", I clicked on the "file" menu and then under "advanced", selected "Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)", and then the folder was not marked virtual.

I can keep my workspace relative paths in the project properties now.

Thank you very much,